# How can I disable the update notice for non-administrators?

Tags: user-roles, updates, customization

As I already told, I'm setting up a Blog for a friend. Next to not being him an administrator [but an editor that can make changes to theme options](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/how-can-i-allow-the-editor-role-to-change-theme-settings)) I have an additional question.

I don't want him to worry about updates as well nor do I want him bothering me, but the problem is, editors do see a slightly changed variant of the update nag.

Is there a way to disable those for non-admins?

It's just the case that we normally do know about Wordpress updates even before they get packaged and released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to adjust the capability.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'hide_update_msg', 1 );
function hide_update_msg()
{
    ! current_user_can( 'install_plugins' ) 
        and remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
}
```

Comment: Basically right, but it's `admin_init` where you need to hook into. Then it works. Thanks!

Comment: @hakre `init` fires in the backend too, but I changed the code to `admin_init`. It is more clear this way.

Comment: when init had fired in the backend, the filter `update_nag` had no hooks registered, with admin_init it had. My (your) callback was fired with both hooks, but for init there was nothing to remove. Just FYI.