# Plugin access and Roles

Tags: plugins, user-roles

I'm new to Wordpress and am a little confused with which Wordpress user types can access plugin functionality?

As administator I know I can activate (and deactivate) plugins. I can access their settings through the dashboard. However, this doesn't seem to be the case for the editor user.

Which plugins settings (if any) are editable for an editor?

The reason for me asking is because I want to manage my clients sites, but there may be some plugin settings that I will want my clients to use. I am assuming that the best way of working will be me as administrator and my clients as editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default only super admins/administrators can edit plugin/theme settings.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table

If you want to give access to plugin/theme settings (or other stuff) for an editor you can add a capability to a role.
[How can I allow the Editor Role to change Theme Settings?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/how-can-i-allow-the-editor-role-to-change-theme-settings)